# Google Maps suggests bad direction

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am currently working with the Google Maps API to render directions.

From the technical side everything works fine:

```
var $canvas = $element.querySelector('#map-canvas');

vvar map = new maps.Map($canvas, {
    center: new maps.LatLng(52.46004869999999, 13.37898690),
    mapTypeId: maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    zoom: 14
});

var route = {
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.BICYCLING,
    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(52.455833, 13.322948),
    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(52.459281, 13.356367),
};

new google.maps.DirectionsService().route(route, function(body) {
    var display = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

    display.setMap(map);
    display.setDirections(body);
});
```

Unfortunately the suggested route is absolutely crap. Instead of going directly from A to B it even leaves the city...

Why does this work good with maps.google.com but not with the API? What do I have to change so I get a correct result?

Bodo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The origin is placed on a train station, it seems the DirectionsService suggests to put the car on a train, because there is a vehicle Shipping available.

Google-Maps doesn't use the exact origin,  it seems that  it geocodes the LatLng and takes the result with type "street_address"(it's Berlinickestraße 16A, 12165 Berlin, Deutschland) as origin.

You may do the same(geocode the LatLng's first and use the results with a type of `street_address` as origin and destination)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I do not understand where I can set type of origin and destination to street address? The geocode response does not contain a result with type street_address (only train station, the other results are not matching at all)

Comment: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html#q%3D52.455833%2C13.322948  , the 2nd result is Berlinickestraße 16A with types set to street_address